# Fancybox using a hyperlink in the title

Tags: url, fancybox, title

Spent hours trying to get a basic url link into fancybox title I have added the HTML for reference

```
title="&lt;a href=&quot;/contactus&quot;&gt;Order Now&lt;/a&gt;  - Title description"
```

I really thought I was loosing it something so basic and simple
Hope this helps

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class_of_your_fancybox").fancybox({
    'showCloseButton' : false,
    'titlePosition'   : 'inside',
    'titleFormat'     : "<a href="/contactus">Order Now</a> - Title description"
});
```

http://fancybox.net/blog

Comment: Thanks Derek! Managed to get '$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});' working but your example fails any ideas

Answer (score 0):

So my example is not the correct method and will create errors for others.

Derek's example failed but the closest I got to a link within a title bar was with the following:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

It works with HTML:

```
<a rel="gallery" title="Link1" class="fancybox" href="5_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

But it links to the image rather than the required url link